# Pass a list of URLs to Scrapy function

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a API Python that gets two arguments (URL and a user-defined word) and provides in the JSON file how many times the specified word appears in the URL.

In the meanwhile, I would like to spend more than one URL at a time, a list. I would also like to make the request with AsyncIO. Any suggestion ?

Follow the code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse, abort
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('url')
parser.add_argument('word')
parser.add_argument('ignorecase')

# Função que faz um GET para a URL e retorna quantas vezes a palavra word aparece no conteudo
def count_words_in(url, word, ignore_case):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        data = str(r.text)
        if (str(ignore_case).lower() == 'true'):
            return data.lower().count(word.lower())
        else:
            return data.count(word)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

# Função que inclui 'http://' na url e retorna a URL valida
def validate_url(url):
    if not(url.startswith('http')):
        url = 'http://' + url
    return url


class UrlCrawlerAPI(Resource):
    def get(self):
        try:
            args = parser.parse_args()
            valid_url = validate_url(args['url'])
            return { valid_url : { args['word'] : count_words_in(valid_url, args['word'], args['ignorecase']) }}
        except AttributeError:
            return { 'message' : 'Please provide URL and WORD arguments' }
        except Exception as e:
            return { 'message' : 'Unhandled Exception: ' + str(e) }


api.add_resource(UrlCrawlerAPI, "/")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```